# How to work with Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redis

Having trouble understanding javascript objects in the particular script im trying to use. if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great. please understand im new to javascript. and trying to learn while coding. so it may not be the prettiest.

```js
var Cryptsy = require('cryptsy');
    redis = require('redis');
    client = redis.createClient()

var cryptsy = new Cryptsy('key', 'secret');

var obj = new Number(obj);

client.hget("Pool_Stats:CurrentShift:WorkerBTC", "Total", function (err, obj) {
    console.dir(obj);
    var obj = new Number(obj);
});

cryptsy.api('makewithdrawal', { address: '13WjD67H382MU8AqA6FyAU5VaKyXzQ35Kr', amount: 'obj' }, function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(err);
});


client.quit();
```

Comment: i think its better to move your code to code review

Comment: I think you should start with a simpler project

Comment: Code Review is only for working code.  If the code is not working, the question will be closed as off-topic.

Comment: my code is working just fine. node-cryptsy is needed to be installed. aswell as a working redis server. i know what im trying to do and the code works. what i cant figure out is how to use the object i've created in console.dir(obj) obj is a decimal number like so "0.01234567" and use it in the amount area of the cryptsy.api command

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here - the most likely problem you're having here is that the functions `client.hget` and `cryptsy.api` are asynchronous - not blocking. By re-arranging your code so the `cryptsy.api` call runs from inside the callback function of `client.hget` you can make one execute after the other:

```
client.hget("Pool_Stats:CurrentShift:WorkerBTC", "Total", function (err, obj) {
    console.dir(obj);
    var obj = new Number(obj);

    cryptsy.api('makewithdrawal', { address: '13WjD67H382MU8AqA6FyAU5VaKyXzQ35Kr', amount: obj }, function (err, data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(err);
    });

    client.quit();
});
```

---

Alternately, if these are blocking functions (or at least `client.hget` is), you could create a variable in root scope, assign to it within the `client.hget` callback function, then use that updated value in the following call:

```
var obj;
client.hget("Pool_Stats:CurrentShift:WorkerBTC", "Total", function (err, obj) {
    console.dir(obj);
    obj = new Number(obj);
});

cryptsy.api('makewithdrawal', { address: '13WjD67H382MU8AqA6FyAU5VaKyXzQ35Kr', amount: 'obj' }, function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(err);
});
```

However considering the standard way node works, you most likely are dealing with asynchronous functions, so the first example above is most likely what you're looking for.

Comment: ahhh okay now that makes perfect sense ! i think the problem may be the first you brought up about being asynchronous. ill let you know tomorrow if the post above fixes me up.

Comment: Perfect you definitely sent me in the right direction. i had to remove the line `var obj = new Number(obj);` and change the obj in the cryptsy.api line to (obj) while removing the quotes around it.